# Data Inserted But Record are Not Showing In database

Tags: sql

The data is being inserted in the database by the user and that data is visible on the user panel but the data is not showing in the database.[record inserted https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGC7C.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEhLi.png)

what is the problem which side customer support forwerd me is here

Comment: The problem might be with SQL result view not able to show this chars.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to execute also **commit** after insert?

Answer (score 0):

Check your table field collation (character set).
**utf8mb4_unicode_ci** It will accept maximum of the languages